# Associations and Collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Controller

```
def new 
  @book=Book.new
  @subjects=Subject.find(:all)
end
```

Model

```
belongs_to :subject
attr_accessible :title, :description, :subject_id
validates_presence_of :title,:description
```

View

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b><%= f.label 'Title' %></b></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b><%= f.label 'Description' %></b></td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :description %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b><%= f.label 'Subject' %></b></td>
        <td><%= f.collection_select(:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.submit 'Save' %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When im trying to save without filling in title and description itz showin me the above error. if im fillin the title and description then itz workin good. Can anyone plz help me?

Comment: if you don't care asking a question with readable codes, you can't expect someone to care answering. i've edited your code for better readabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2> Add New Book </h2>
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
<% if @book.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>


<table>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Title' %></b></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :title %></td></tr>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Description' %></b></td>
<td><%= f.text_area :description %></td></tr>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Subject' %></b></td>
<td><%= f.collection_select(:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></td></tr>

<tr><td><%= f.submit 'Save' %></td></tr>

 </table>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_url %>
```

this is my view code. if i remove the collection_select from my view code, then itz showin validation errors like title cant be blank or description cant be blank if im not fillin anythin and tryin to save... but when im using collection_select itz showing me (Error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass)... but i want validation errors like title or description cant be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Error:
     NoMethodError in Books#create

Showing C:/work/Library/app/views/books/new.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #21):

```
18:     <td><%= f.text_area :description %></td></tr>
19: 
20: <tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Subject' %></b></td>
21:     <td><%= f.collection_select(:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></td></tr>
22: 
23: <tr><td><%= f.submit 'Save' %></td></tr>
```

Controller:
      class BooksController < ApplicationController

```
before_filter :self_load, :only=>[:edit,:show,:update,:destroy]

def index
 @books=Book.where(:subject_id=>params[:id])
end

def new 
 @book=Book.new
 @subjects=Subject.all
end

def create 
 @book=Book.new(params[:book])
   if @book.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice=>'New Book has been added'
   else 
    render :action=>'new'
   end
end

def edit
end

def update
 if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
   redirect_to books_path, :notice=>'Book has been updated'
else
   render :action=>'edit'
end
end

def show
end

def destroy
 @book.destroy
 redirect_to root_url
end

def self_load
 @book=Book.find(params[:id])
end
end

class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :self_load, :only=>[:edit,:show,:update,:destroy]

def index
 @subjects=Subject.all
 @books=Book.all
end

def new 
 @subject=Subject.new
end

def create 
 @subject=Subject.new(params[:subject])
if @subject.save
   redirect_to root_url, :notice=>'New subject has been added'
else 
   render :action=>'new'
end
end

def edit
end

def update
 if @subject.update_attributes(params[:subject])
   redirect_to root_url, :notice=>'Subject has been updated'
else
   render :action=>'edit'
end
end

def show
end

def destroy
 @subject.destroy
 redirect_to root_url
end

def self_load
 @subject=Subject.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

MOdel:
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 belongs_to :subject

 attr_accessible :title, :description, :subject_id

 validates_presence_of :title,:description

 validates_uniqueness_of :title

 validates_length_of :title, :in=>3..20

 validates_length_of :description, :minimum=>5

end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :books, :dependent=> :destroy

 attr_accessible :name

 validates_presence_of :name

 validates_uniqueness_of :name

 validates_length_of :name, :in=>3..10

end
```

view:

### Add New Book

<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    <% if @book.errors.any? %>

  <% @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
- <%= msg %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

```
<table>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Title' %></b></td>
 <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td></tr>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Description' %></b></td>
 <td><%= f.text_area :description %></td></tr>

<tr><td><b><%= f.label 'Subject' %></b></td>
 <td><%= f.collection_select(:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %></td></tr>

<tr><td><%= f.submit 'Save' %></td></tr>

</table>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_url %>
```

when im trying to add a new book and m keeping the title and description empty and tryin to save, im gettin undefined method map error.. if i remove the collection_select from my view source and then im tryin to add a new book and keepin the description and title empty and trying to save it, itz showin that the title and description should not be empty... when collection_select is there in my view source and if im fillin the title and description and tryin to save it.... it is working

Answer (score -1):

In your model, you've explicitly added validation to check for title and description.

```
validates_presence_of :title, :description
```

If you remove the above line from your model, you can save without these values.

This is the answer to your line line (except the mentioned error). But you didn't show us the code in controller (`create` action) that is actually creating the object.

Comment: even i knw that without using validations ill not get error but i dint understand why im gettin error if im usin validations......... actually i want to use validations, so that the object doesnt save if the title and description are empty...

Comment: can anyone solve the above question?????/ i want to use validations too. if anymore code is reqd, ill provide. thx in advance

Comment: i do not understand your question. when validation exists, you must enter those fields. otherwise you will get validation error.

Comment: im having error code too. if i get any error it displays the validation errors. ill show u my full code

Comment: im using rails 3.2.13... i've tried the code which u hav told but still am  facin the same problem......

Comment: if u want to go thru my entire code... go thru this https://github.com/nav0285/Libray

Comment: can you inspect your `@subjects`  to see what it contains?

Comment: it contains 3 subjects.... biology, chemistry and physics. in my view, im getting this subjects also..

Comment: please update your question with the actual error message with file names and line numbers.